# Selecting only one column when using distinct

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I select only the `property_id` from this query?

```
select distinct(property_name), property_id from prop where property_name 
like '%blah%';
```

I am trying to insert new rows to the table `app_prop` with the `property_id` exactly like the query above, so something similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO app_prop (function, PROPERTY_ID)
VALUES('dataq', select distinct(property_name), property_id from prop 
where property_name like '%blah%');
-- only want property_id included NOT property_name --
```

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the `property_id`, then select only that.

Also: when using a `select` statement as a source for an `insert` statement, do not use the `values` clause.

To only insert distinct values for property_id you can use this:

```
INSERT INTO app_prop (function, PROPERTY_ID)
select distinct 'dataq', property_id 
from prop 
where property_name like '%blah%'
```

Comment: but i need distinct `property_name` because there are multiple duplicate rows and each row has a unique property_id.

Comment: Oh i just saw your comment about how distinct is not a function. No wonder it's not a function. Thanks!

Comment: @robben: the query **will** insert only distinct values for `property_id`. There is no need to include `property_name` in the select list if you only care about `property_id`